# Hide columns in DataListView (Part of ObjectListView control)

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am using a the DataListView control part of the ObjectListView control in my application. I have four entities in my application, Location, Machine, Fault and MantainanceSchedule. I do have the data source object Location for my application to navigate and work with data in my database. The entity Location, that is, my object location have a collection of entities Machines associated with it. My DataListView control data source is linked to the instance of collection of machines entities of each instance of a location. Each machine entity have in turn a collection of Faults and MantainanceSchedules associated with it. Now, per every location I am navigating into in my application, I want to view a list of all machines information associated with it in a DataListView. I am able to view the information in a DataListView. However, because, each machine entity have other entities associated with, I have three columns that I do not want to show on my DataListView - Faults, Location and MantainanceShedules.

Please note, I am populating data in my DataListView at runtime so my DataListView columns are created automatically from the properties of my datasource object Location. I am using entity framwework. Please see the code that is generating my DataListView columns and the image with columns marked with an X that I do not need to show in my DataListView when Iam running my program.

```
Location loc = (Location)locationBindingNavigator.BindingSource.Current;
dataListViewMachines.DataSource = loc.Machines.ToList();
```

How can I hide these columns which I do not want to show in my DataListView?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems I finally got answer to my own question. The answer seems very simple but I struggled to reach there. So, I am sharing this with people like me. All I have done is removing the unwanted DataListView columns at runtime that I identified by the keys of my header. In this case, the columns that I did not want to show were Location, Faults and MaintainanceSchedules.

```
dataListViewMachines.Columns.RemoveByKey("Location");
dataListViewMachines.Columns.RemoveByKey("MantainanceSchedules");
dataListViewMachines.Columns.RemoveByKey("Faults");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`.